# Is this application of the law of total probability correct?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, conditional-probability

Let us consider a counting process $N(t)_{t\geq0}$ which is neither Markovian nor Levy. Is it correct to write

$$
\mathbb{P}(N(t)=j)=\int_{0}^{t}\mathbb{P}(N(t)=j, N(s)=i)ds
$$

for $j\geq 1$ and $i\leq j$?

Thanks in advance.